# How do I write a String to an already existing text file on my desktop?

Tags: java, string, file, text

I want to know how to write a String to an already existing file that is on my desktop.

This text file will already have information in it so I want it to be wiped.

Thank You

Comment: Easily doable. `FileOutputStream` will open a file. Write to it. Close the file. Did you even Google?

Comment: I tried to use that however it didn't output the whole text only 2 letters

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does write some text to the file without deleting the previous data.

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;


try
{
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sample.txt",true));
    }catch(IOException  e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR:"+e);
        return;
    }

try
{
    bw.write("\r\ntext you want to write to the file");
    bw.close();
}catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR:"+e);
}

}
```

Now if you want the data to be deleted then just replace the line:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sample.txt",true));
```

with the following:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sample.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("yourLocation.txt"));
String s = "hello world";
p.printf(s);
p.close();
```